# Multi-2D Array Breadth First Search Java

Tags: java, dictionary, multidimensional-array, coordinates, breadth-first-search

I'm trying to create a method in a class for Java for a game called Quoridor in which a Pawn has to reach the other side of the board. The Pawn class (one coordinate) traverses a 9x9 2D array whereas the Wall classes (2 coordinates) are placed on a 10x10 2D array. The Walls are basically placed between the Pawn squares. Pawns cant cross Walls or other Pawns, I'm not sure how to implement the BFS with two 2D arrays. I'm new to programming and was wondering if someone could give me a step by step on how to create such a method. Currently have a Pawn and Wall class with necessary get and set methods.`enter code here`

```
package Players.HaydenLindquist;

import java.util.*;

import Engine.Logger;
import Interface.Coordinate;
import Interface.PlayerModule;
import Interface.PlayerMove;

public class HaydenLindquist implements PlayerModule {

    Coordinate newCoords;
    Wall theWall;
    private Logger logOut;
    Pawn player;
    Pawn opponent;
    List<Wall> wallList;
    List<Pawn> pawnList;

    public int getID() 
    {
        return player.getId();
    }

    public Set<Coordinate> getNeighbors(Coordinate c) {

        // Creates HashSet we will use to store neighbor tiles
        Set<Coordinate> neighbor = new HashSet<Coordinate>();

        int x = c.getRow();
        int y = c.getCol();

        // Coordinates for the 4 adjacent spaces
        Coordinate top = new Coordinate(x,y-1);
        Coordinate bottom = new Coordinate(x,y+1);
        Coordinate left = new Coordinate(x-1,y);
        Coordinate right = new Coordinate(x+1,y);

        if(x == 0) {
            if(y == 0) {
                if(! wallCheck(right))
                    neighbor.add(right);
                if(! wallCheck(bottom))
                    neighbor.add(bottom);
            }
            else if(y == 8) {
                if(! wallCheck(top))
                    neighbor.add(top);
                if(! wallCheck(right))
                    neighbor.add(right);
            }
            else {
                if(! wallCheck(top))
                    neighbor.add(top);
                if(! wallCheck(right))
                    neighbor.add(right);
                if(! wallCheck(bottom))
                    neighbor.add(bottom);
            }
        }

        else if(x == 8) {
            if(y == 0) {
                if(! wallCheck(left))
                    neighbor.add(left);
                if(! wallCheck(bottom))
                    neighbor.add(bottom);
            }
            else if(y == 8) {
                if(! wallCheck(top))
                    neighbor.add(top);
                if(! wallCheck(left))
                    neighbor.add(left);
            }
            else {
                if(! wallCheck(top))
                    neighbor.add(top);
                if(! wallCheck(left))
                    neighbor.add(left);
                if(! wallCheck(bottom))
                    neighbor.add(bottom);
            }
        }

        else if(y == 0) {
            if(! wallCheck(right))
                neighbor.add(right);
            if(! wallCheck(left))
                neighbor.add(left);
            if(! wallCheck(bottom))
                neighbor.add(bottom);
        }

        else if(y == 8) {
            if(! wallCheck(right))
                neighbor.add(right);
            if(! wallCheck(left))
                neighbor.add(left);
            if(! wallCheck(top))
                neighbor.add(top);
        }

        else {
            if(! wallCheck(right))
                neighbor.add(right);
            if(! wallCheck(left))
                neighbor.add(left);
            if(! wallCheck(top))
                neighbor.add(top);
            if(! wallCheck(bottom))
                neighbor.add(bottom);
        }      
        return neighbor;         
    } 

    /**
     * 
     */
    public Coordinate getPlayerLocation(int playerID) 
    {         
        if(playerID == player.getId()) 
        {
            return(player.getLocation());
        }
        else return(opponent.getLocation());         
    }

    /**
     * 
     */
    public Map<Integer, Coordinate> getPlayerLocations() {

        // Creates HashMap of Integer, Coordinate type
        HashMap<Integer, Coordinate> locations = new HashMap<Integer, Coordinate>();

        // Adds the ID and locations of the 2 players to the HashMap
        locations.put(player.getId(), player.getLocation());
        locations.put(opponent.getId(), opponent.getLocation());    

        return locations;
    }


    /**
     * 
     */
    public List<Coordinate> getShortestPath(Coordinate start, Coordinate end) 
    {
        List<Coordinate> path = new ArrayList<Coordinate>();


        return null;
    }


    /**
     * 
     */
    public int getWallsRemaining(int playerID) 
    {         
        if(playerID == player.getId()) 
        {
            return(player.getWalls());
        }
        else return(opponent.getWalls());
    }


    /**
     * 
     */
    public void init(Logger logger, int playerID, int numWalls, Map<Integer, Coordinate> playerHomes) 
    {         
        logOut = logger;         
        // Creates ArrayList used to store wall objects
        wallList = new ArrayList<Wall>();         
        // Creates our two players and initializes them with data from engine
        for ( Integer i : (Set<Integer>) playerHomes.keySet() ) 
        {
            if ( i == playerID )
                player = new Pawn(playerID,numWalls,playerHomes.get(i));
            else 
            {
                opponent = new Pawn(2,numWalls,playerHomes.get(i));
            }
        }   
    }

    public void lastMove(PlayerMove m) 
    {         
        // Check if m is a player move or wall placement
        if(m.isMove()) 
        {            
            // Switch to differentiate between player 1 and 2.
            // then updates the appropriate players location
            switch(m.getPlayerId()) 
            {             
            case 1:
                player.setLocation(m.getEnd());
                break;

            case 2:
                opponent.setLocation(m.getEnd());
                break;
            }   
        }         
        else 
        {             
            switch(m.getPlayerId()) 
            {            
            case 1:
                addWall(m.getStart(), m.getEnd());
                player.setWalls(player.getWalls() - 1);
                break;

            case 2:
                addWall(m.getStart(), m.getEnd());
                opponent.setWalls(player.getWalls() - 1);
                break;
            }       
        }
    }


    /**
     * 
     */
    public Set<PlayerMove> allPossibleMoves() 
    {
        return null;
    }


    /**
     * 
     */
    public PlayerMove move() 
    {
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param player
     * @return
     */


    /**
     * 
     *
     */
    public void playerInvalidated(int playerID) 
    {

    }

    /**
     * Method that creates a new wall object and adds it to the wallList ArrayList
     * 
     * @param start
     * @param end
     */
    public void addWall(Coordinate start, Coordinate end) 
    {
        Wall w = new Wall(start,end);
        wallList.add(w);                 
    }

    /**
     * A check method to see if entered coordinate contains a section of a wall
     * 
     * @param c
     * @return
     */
    public boolean wallCheck(Coordinate c) 
    {
        // Iterates through wall objects in wallList
        for(int i = 0; i < wallList.size(); i++) 
        {            
            // Check if any adjacent squares contain a section of a wall
            if(wallList.get(i).isWall(c)) 
            {
                return true;
            }
        }         
        return false;         
    }   
}
```

Comment: Do you have any code at all so far?

Comment: I just added our main class where we have our shortestPath() method we are working on. Not sure how to tackle it

Answer (score 0):

Since you're starting with the idea of a BFS, *and* you've decided to represent your board with multidimensional arrays, why don't you start by thinking about how BFS maps to the representation of your board?

For example, can you write up the code to list all adjacent cells of a given cell? If you can do that, it should be easier to see how to implement the rest of BFS.

Comment: I updated my post and added our "main class"  any help would be amazing